# Advice on data reload between Tableview and viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

This is just to as for advice for the best way to do the following;

I have a tableview which is populated by two arrays; when rowatindexpath is selected takes me to another viewcontroller which displays the data. All is working fine: however, I need to move back to the tableview to display the same data (which now has been released). which would be the best procedure to call back the data? do I pass the data back and forth between the tableview everytime or write the data to a plist and call it back on tableview reload.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass data down a stack of controllers the usual approach is to use a delegate protocol on the 'detail' VC that is implemented by the 'master' VC.

It's a common question - I've got an example application that demonstrates this https://bitbucket.org/abizern/delegation-example

Which reminds me, I should update it for iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be achieved by reloadData in `viewWillAppear:` method.
make a NSMutableArray in SingletonClass or in your application's AppDelegate and update/delete values from it from your DetailView

Once you are in your UITableView VC just `reloadData` in `viewWillAppear:`